# Activity with transparent background and blur-filter

Tags: java, android, android-activity, transparent, blur

I'm currently working on an application where I at one point want to open an Activity that has a transparent background so that I can see the activity below it. This was simple enough and I solved it quick. However, now I want to also add some kind of blur filter so that the activity below my activity seems blurred out.

I have searched around and tried several different solutions but with no luck so I'm trying to add this as a question. Does anyone know of any good way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hello JesperQV. If my answer is useful for u please vote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of libraries that do this. [Here's](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/176) one list of them. Personally I've used [BlurView](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView) (I hope linking to one of the libraries is not against site rules) but I've had to patch the library a bit, see [this issue](https://github.com/Dimezis/BlurView/issues/41) - the pull request is not in yet. I've also had performance issues with animations.

Basically all the libraries do the same things:

- Create Canvas for a Bitmap, with scaled down dimensions (e.g. 4 times smaller), set the transformation matrix to apply this scaling
- Render the background of the window to Canvas
- Render the root view of the Activity to the Canvas
- Blur the Canvas's Bitmap using ScriptIntrinsicBlur
- Draw the Bitmap as the background of a View, scaled back up e.g. 4 times

Why the scaling? For performance reasons. It's much faster to draw everything 4 times smaller, and also the blur effect becomes "stronger" due to the upscaling - there's a limit how much ScriptIntrinsicBlur can blur with one pass, and multiple passes slow things down again.

Answer (score 0):

For API < 14, you could use the flag WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND.
For higher APIS this is no longer supported.

However, you could do this with a view.

Create a Bitmap from your activity's overall layout and Blur that bitmap with whatever method you want. Add(or unhide) a View in your layout that covers everything and you have your problem solved.